# Click link if h1 and p is equal to variable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If i have something like this:

```js
<div class="inner-article">
  <h1><a class="name-link" href="link">Exempel 1</a></h1>
  <p><a class="name-link" href="link">a</a></p>
</div>
<div class="inner-article">
  <h1><a class="name-link" href="link">Exempel 2</a></h1>
  <p><a class="name-link" href="link">a</a></p>
</div>
<div class="inner-article">
  <h1><a class="name-link" href="link">Exempel 2</a></h1>
  <p><a class="name-link" href="link">b</a></p>
</div>
<div class="inner-article">
  <h1><a class="name-link" href="link">Exempel 3</a></h1>
  <p><a class="name-link" href="link">a</a></p>
</div>
```

And i wanted to click the link if h1 = var1 and p = var2
I have this code:

```js
var var1 = "Exempel 2";
var var2 = "a";

    $( "h1 > a" ).each(function( index ) {
          if($( this ).text() == var1){
          $( this )[0].click();
      }
     });
```

The code works fine but the problem is, when there are more h1 with the same text, it opens both links and end up on the last link.
So how do i open the right link?

Comment: Can u be specific about question. I am confused

Comment: It's hard for me to desribe but i'll try my best. I want to click a link on a webpage if the text is equel to the variables. But sometimes the text is the same in the <h1> tag but under there is a <p> tag. So what i want is to is: if var1 = h1 and p = h2 then click link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the text from both the `h1` and the adiacent `p` match your criteria.

```
var var1 = "Exempel 2";
var var2 = "a";

    $( "h1 > a" ).each(function( index ) {
             if($( this ).text() == var1 && 
                   $( this ).closest('div').find("p > a").text() == var2) {
                $( this )[0].click();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**this should work.It serves less loops**

```
 var var1 = "Exempel 2"; 
var var2 = "a"; 

$( "div" ).each(function( index ) {         
    if($( this ).find('a:first').text() == var1 && $( this ).find('a:last').text()  == var2)
       $( this ).find('a:first').click()
       return false;
     }  
});
```

Comment: This may work in some cases, but only if the link he is looking for is the first one in the list.